# Command line random slideshow which shows latest images first

Tags: bash, shell, unix, raspberry-pi, slideshow

I'm currently building a Photo Booth with a Raspberry Pi 2 running Rasparian and got some issues with the slideshow. 
All taken pictures are stored in one directory and I would like to run a slideshow which shuffles all photos. If the user takes a new picture the slideshow should pause and display the new picture for some seconds, after that it should continue with the random slideshow.

```
pqiv --watch-directories --sort-key=mtime --sort --end-of-files-action=wait --slideshow-interval=0.001 --slideshow [directory]
```

I tried to do this with pqiv but it doesn't worked out as I hoped it will. The slideshow over runs the other images and just shows the latest one.

Any idea to run this slideshow as I explained it? I use bash and python scripts for the booth.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```
random_img() {
    find "$DEST"/* | shuf -n1 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I don't know what to do with this code. I put it in a shell scipt, changed the path and run it, but nothing happend.

Comment: You just pass a list of file names to `shuf -n1` and then it returns a random one. if that's what you wanted. for example; `find . -iname "*.jpg" | shuf -n1`